# Primefaces - Update modal dialog

Tags: generics, primefaces, modal-dialog

I have a problem using a primeface modal dialog that is loaded from an external xhtml-file.

My intention is: pressing the button should invoke the method "setType" with the parameter "T" (the reason for invoking this method is to reuse the dialog depending on the type). During this method the DualList inside the dialog.xhtml will be reloaded with the correct and type-depending data. After that the dialog should be shown.

My current code is :

```
<p:commandButton
value="#{bean.value}"
id="button" type="button" icon="ui-icon-newwin"
onclick="varDialog.show()" style="width: 70px;">

<p:ajax listener="#{bean.setType('T'.charAt(0))}"
    update="dialog" />

<p:dialog id="dialog"
    widgetVar="varDialog"
    header="Dialog Header"
    resizable="false" modal="true" dynamic="true" width="900"
    appendToBody="true">
    <ui:include src="dialog.xhtml" />
</p:dialog>
</p:commandButton>
```

The problem is that the dialog will disappear right after it is shown (my guess is this is because of the 'update="dialog"'). But leaving out this code will end in a dialog without visible data.

So my question is: how do i achieve to load a generic external dialog with specific type depending data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself reading this thread: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18503

The first mistake i made was a nested  (one in the main.xhtml and one in the included dialog.xhtml). So - with the help of the thread - i changed the code to the following:

```
<h:form>
<p:commandButton
    value="#{bean.value}"
    id="supplierButton" icon="ui-icon-newwin"
    actionListener="#{bean.prepareDialog('T'.charAt(0))}"
    oncomplete="varDialog.show()"
    update=":tabView:dialog"
    immediate="true" style="width: 70px;">
</p:commandButton>
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="dialog"
    widgetVar="varDialog"
    header="Dialog title"
    resizable="false" modal="true" dynamic="true" width="900"
    appendToBody="true">
    <ui:include src="dialog.xhtml" />
</p:dialog>
```

This works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use AJAX in this case? I would set up an action:

```
<p:commandButton
    value="#{bean.value}"
    id="button"
    type="button"
    icon="ui-icon-newwin"
    style="width: 70px;"
    action="#{bean.prepareDialog}">
```

Inside the bean:

```
public void prepareDialog() {
    // Do your things.

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("dialogWidget.show()");
}
```

And there is a bug in PF which will require you to enclose a dynamic dialogue in a conditional if part of a composition, else it would just load and ignore the dynamic. This may apply to your scenario, but I can't assess it just seeing your example code.

```
<c:if test="#{bean.condition != null}">
    <ui:include src="dialog.xhtml"/>
</c:if>
```